# How to speed up Google colab when doing random search in sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, google-colaboratory

The following code takes 5.0 minutes to execute on Google colab while on my machine it takes around 3.0 minutes. In all other tasks (machine learning or otherwise) I tested, colab beat my machine by 50-100 %.
I tried installing different sklearn versions, running with GPU and also experimenting with n_jobs values but the time either got slower or remained the same.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV, KFold
from datetime import datetime

param_grid = [
    {'feature_selection': [RFE(estimator=GradientBoostingClassifier(random_state=0))],
     'feature_selection__n_features_to_select': [2],
     'scaling': [StandardScaler()],
     'classification': [GradientBoostingClassifier(random_state=0)],
     'classification__n_estimators': [100, 500],
     'classification__max_features': ['auto', 'log2'],
     'classification__max_depth': [2, 4],
     'classification__learning_rate': [0.01, ],
     'classification__loss': ['exponential'],
     'classification__min_samples_split': [2, 200],
     'classification__min_samples_leaf': [1, 20]},

    {'feature_selection': [RFE(estimator=LogisticRegression(random_state=0))],
     'feature_selection__n_features_to_select': [2],
     'scaling': [StandardScaler()],
     'classification': [LogisticRegression(random_state=0)],
     'classification__C': [0.1, 100, 1000],
     'classification__penalty': ['l1'],
     'classification__solver': ['liblinear']}
]

pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('scaling', StandardScaler()),
                       ('feature_selection', RFE(estimator=GradientBoostingClassifier())),
                       ('classification', GradientBoostingClassifier())])

grid_obj = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=pipe, param_distributions=param_grid,
                              scoring='neg_brier_score', cv=KFold(shuffle=True), random_state=0,
                              return_train_score=True, n_jobs=-1, verbose=10)

X, y = load_breast_cancer(return_X_y=True)
grid_obj.fit(X, y)
```

Google colab results:

```
# [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 2 concurrent workers.
# [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   1 tasks      | elapsed:   13.3s
# [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   4 tasks      | elapsed:   25.8s
# [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   9 tasks      | elapsed:  1.0min
# [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  14 tasks      | elapsed:  1.4min
# [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  21 tasks      | elapsed:  2.2min
# [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  28 tasks      | elapsed:  2.8min
# [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  37 tasks      | elapsed:  3.8min
# [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  46 tasks      | elapsed:  4.6min
# [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  50 out of  50 | elapsed:  5.0min finished
```